# numpy.square returns incorrect result for sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

`numpy.square` seems to give incorrect output when `scipy.sparse` matrices are passed to it:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as S
a = np.array([np.arange(5), np.arange(5), np.arange(5), np.arange(5), np.arange(5)])

a
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])

np.square(a)
# array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16],
#        [ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16],
#        [ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16],
#        [ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16],
#        [ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16]])

b = S.lil_matrix(a)
c = np.square(b)
c
# <5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
#   with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

c[2,2]
# 20
# Expected output is 4, as in np.square(a) output above.
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, passing in `scipy.sparse` matrices into `numpy` functions that take arrays ("array_like") as input, results to undefined/unintended behavior.

There is no automatic `sparse -> dense` cast.

Numpy does not know anything about Scipy's sparse matrices.

Sparse matrices are not "array_like" in the sense understood by Numpy.
What the numpy functions then do is to treat the sparse matrices as just some Python objects of an unknown type --- in general resulting to putting them to 1-element object arrays, and working on from there. For returning scalar results, the temporary object array is discarded and just the object contained inside it is returned, so it's easy to miss that something strange was actually done.

Object arrays have some fallbacks for performing arithmetic etc operations on their elements (unknown Python objects), including calling `operator.mul` of the element if `*` needs to be performed and so on. This then combined with the above results to the behavior you see.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As pointed out by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), the reason is probably a bit more involved. `np.square` is able to detect `np.matrix` and is able to square the elements. However, it falters on `sp.sparse.*matrix`.

---

This is not a bug; this is the subtle difference between how `numpy` and `scipy` implement the `__mul__` operator. By default, `*` for `numpy.ndarray` performs element-wise multiplication whereas for `numpy.matrix` (and consequently, for `scipy.sparse.*matrix`), it performs matrix multiplication (from [PEP 465](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/#background-what-s-wrong-with-the-status-quo)):

> `numpy` provides two different types with different `__mul__` methods. For
>   `numpy.ndarray` objects, `*` performs elementwise multiplication, and
>   matrix multiplication must use a function call (`numpy.dot`). For
>   `numpy.matrix` objects, `*` performs matrix multiplication, and
>   elementwise multiplication requires function syntax.

Internally, `numpy.square` uses the provided argument's `__mul__` method, which is different for `ndarray`s and `matrix`es.

Comment: `np.square` documentation says it does element by element multliplication.  It does that for `np.matrix` objects.  For some obsure reason, with `sparse` matrix objects it is doing the matrix multiplication.  The calling stack is, I think, a mix of C and Python code that is hard to follow.